# MySQL Greater Than current datetime issue

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
check deal_time field value in phpmyadmin is less than or greater than current datetime stamp.
deal_time value stored in database in format('y/m/d h:m:s') 2012-12-17 11:05:28;
```

condition  ->

```
  $WhereBy = $this->db->dbprefix("product").".`Active` = 'Y' and ".$this->db->dbprefix("product"). ".`Deal_Time` <= NOW()"   ;
```

but it return wrong result . Please tell what the problem . Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "but it return wrong result ." What was wrong? Can you show what result you got, and what you expected to get?

Comment: and also show us your database sample values & schema

Answer (score 3):

i think it's h:i:s not h:m:s because you would get month val for minutes

Answer (score 0):

Try 
date(Deal_Time)<= NOW()